# custom template tag function not calling

Tags: django, django-templates

Template code:

```
{% extends 'some.html' %}
{% load tag %}
{% get_rate land contDetails.postcode contDetails.county title uid LsAff.aff_id LsAff.group_id %}
```

custom template tag:

```
 from django import template
 from process.utils.error_handler import  debug_logger
 from django.template import Library, Node, TemplateSyntaxError
 class land(template.Node):
   def __init__(self, var):
      self.varname = template.Variable(var)
      debug_logger().info(self.varname)

   def render(self, context):
     debug_logger().info("hello")
     user = self.varname.resolve(context)
     debug_logger().info("hello")
     debug_logger().info(user)
     return "somestring"

def get_rate(parser, token):
   debug_logger().info("hell")
   bits=token.split_contents()
   var=bits[2]
   debug_logger().info(var)
   return land(var)
register = template.Library()
register.tag('get_rate', get_rate)
```

In the above code **def render(self, context):** function is not calling.
Till **debug_logger().info(self.varname)**  statement the code works properly.

Am i missing anything? 
please help to find the solution to call render(self, context)

Comment: Can you add your template code?

Comment: any additional error information? maybe add the whole error?

Comment: @cwoebker i m not getting any error it doesn't return anything.While debugging i found that render function is not called.

Comment: alright now i get what you mean, sorry, its just too early in the morning, ill take a look at it and see if i find anyting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a quick view function and replicated your tag. I reduced the number of arguments to two for brevity. Everything is working ok for me.

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_view(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'var' : True})

#tag.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.tag('get_rate')
def get_rate(parser, token):
    bits = token.contents.split()
    var = bits[2]
    return LandNode(var)

class LandNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.varname = template.Variable(var)

    def render(self, context):
        varname = self.varname.resolve(context)
        return 'some string'

#test.html
{% load tag %}
{% get_rate 'foo' var %}
```

Renders:

```
some string
```

I would recommend reducing the method signature on that template tag and just pass in objects where you're passing in multiple object properties.